# How to explode a string with commas and recompose except the first one

Tags: php

I have a string like this `[tubelist dijfisj, ijdsifjad, ajkdfksd, sdjfkdf]` and I would like to separate them into two **`###URL###`** and **`###URL2###`**.

This is the code I got so far

```
function xyz_plugin_callback($match)
{
  $tag_parts = explode(",", rtrim($match[0], "]"));
  $output = YOUX_TARGET;
  $output = str_replace("###URL###", $tag_parts[1], $output);
  $output = str_replace("###URL2###", $tag_parts[2], $output);
}
```

`$match` is the variable that I'm passing in.

Comment: this made more sense before the edit..

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize regular expressions here.

So if you do something like:

```
$temp_match = trim($match[0], "[]");

$urls = array();
preg_match("/([\w\s]*),([\w\s]*),.*/", $temp_match, $urls);

$url1 = $urls[1];
$url2 = $urls[2];

// do your $output str_replace here.
```

Comment: thanks. Once I extract the first one, how would I keep the rest of "ijdsifjad, ajkdfksd, sdjfkdf" as is?

Comment: Edited. The original `match[0]` is unchanged.

Comment: I tried your code and it yielded this.  First ###URL## =tubelist dijfisj and ###URL2### = ijdsifjad.  What I would like to achieve is ###URL### = dijfisj and ###URL2### =  ijdsifjad, ajkdfksd, sdjfkdf

Answer (score 0):

finally, I got it working!  Here is the working code.

```
$tag_parts1 = explode(" ", rtrim($match[0], "]"));

$tag_parts = explode(",",$tag_parts1[1],2);
```

the first line will strip the [tubelist and ].
the second line with store the first set of value in array[0] and the rest to [1].

voila, case resolved.